# How to work with special row after group_by in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame something like bellow:

```
amount <- sample(10000:2000, 20)
year<- sample(2015:2017, 20, replace = TRUE)
company<- sample(LETTERS[1:3],20, replace = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(company, year, amount)
```

Then I want to group by `company` and `year` so I have:

```
df %>%
  group_by(company, year) %>%
  summarise(
    total= sum(amount)
     )

  company  year total
  <fct>   <int> <int>
1 A        2015  1094
2 A        2016  3308
3 A        2017  4785
4 B        2015  1190
5 B        2016  6583
6 B        2017  1964
7 C        2015  4974
8 C        2016  1986
9 C        2017  3465
```

Now, I want to divide the last row in each group to the first row. In other words, I want to divide the `total` value for the last `year` for each `company` to the same value of the first `year`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `last` and `first` to access those elements of `total` respectively :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(company, year) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(amount)) %>%
  summarise(final = last(total)/first(total))

# company final
#  <fct>   <dbl>
#1 A       2.26 
#2 B       1.92 
#3 C       0.565
```

In base R, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(amount~company, aggregate(amount~company+year, df, sum), 
               function(x) x[length(x)]/x[1])

#  company   amount
#1       A 2.262524
#2       B 1.919138
#3       C 0.565281
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to keep `total` in output so I can use it for visualization?

Comment: @Bahman Which `total` value do you need , first or last ? In case, if you just want to add a new column you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise`, `df %>%
  group_by(company, year) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(amount)) %>%
  mutate(final = last(total)/first(total))`

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .(total = sum(amount)), .(company, year)][, 
         .(final = last(total)/first(total)), .(company)]
```